# armv6 and armv7

Tags: ios, armv6

I've got an app that I created that I'm trying to test on an older iphone 3g.  I've used this phone many times for testing but this new app for some reason will not accept the build.

I've done some searching and found that I need to charge the architecture from "armv7" to "armv6", I did this in both the project and target.  After doing that I get the following error when trying to build to the device (construction is the name of the app)

`Could not launch "construction"
No such file or directory (/Users/Matthew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Construction-cqtujdbjhpvbkrehtfzwvuhvxdrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Construction.app/Construction)`

But I can build in the simulator at it works fine... any idea?

Comment: I did also follow that path and past "Xcode" it is not right... but I'm note sure how or why it's looking in that location?

Comment: Sorry I answered my own question!  I figure I should leave this up in case anyone else has the same problem... I didn't update the plist setting to armv6 before... I did have to delete the armv7 in the plist to make it work

Comment: Oh my god I love you. I was having this same problem and nobody could answer it. None of the things I found on this site worked, except for this.

Comment: I can confirm that deleting and re-creating the architectures list seems to fix other submission errors pertaining to architecture also. In my case I had to re-add the same architectures after upgrading to XCode 4.6. BTW, you should write your answer and accept it! Someone finding this question might miss it if it's just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I answered my own question! I figure I should leave this up in case anyone else has the same problem... I didn't update the plist setting to armv6 before... I did have to delete the armv7 in the plist to make it work

Answer (score 7):

thank you so much - clearing `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in `Info.plist` would have never appeared to me.

Comment: who said anything about UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities?

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. I'm using XCode 4.5 and ML. What I ended up doing (and still need to test thoroughly), was to re-create my project, started clean and then moved all sources and libraries to the new project and chose my provisioning profile for this new project. In the copy, I also manually copied the contents of the old Info.plist file and pasted them onto the newly Info.plist replacing them all.

In my case, I'm using CorePlot and that library needs armv7 (according to linker), so I can't just go armv6.

What I'm trying to figure out is when (cheap) XCode changed some settings to not run as a debugger on the device. I'm guessing something in the 'project.pbxproj' file. Otherwise I can't explain why the newly created project works and the old one doesn't.

I know this solution might not work for everyone, as in my case, as would lose all svn changes.

I'll post any progress on this.

My next step is to add CorePlot and let the project build it and not use the prebuilt one.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me either.  But this DID work...

DO THE USUAL THINGS:
I cleared the build directory (cmd-k), 
cleared the DerivedData (see prefs|Locations), 
deleted the app from my iPhone 5,
unplugged the iPhone, and
restarted Xcode.

AND LASTLY DO THIS:
Open Xcode Organizer.  Click on Devices | (your device name) | Applications.  And finally, delete your application from here (aka. delete the app from your device, AGAIN).

Build and run...